# Use python to press and hold keys to move a character in CS GO (FPS game)

Tags: python

I've searched around for hours and haven't found anything that I can get to work, I'm looking for a system that just sends the keypress and its held until a 2nd command is sent releasing the key. this ideally would be done without that delay when you want to spam a letter like"v...vvvvvvvvvvvvv". as I'm working on building a Reinforcement learning bot to 1V1 in cs go and need a way to send inputs.
I'm using **python 3.6**
Many thanks

Comment: check this library https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: Thank you so much that works brilliantly!!!!

Comment: You are welcome :D